# Handling Coinbase API react native redirect with OAuth authorization using react-native-app-auth

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, coinbase-api

I've got OAuth working in React Native using react-native-app-auth. My app redirects to Coinbase for OAuth authorization without a problem. The issue is once authorized how to return to my app with the token. In a web setup you can provide a redirect URI but for mobile does doesn't exist. According to the Coinbase docs the way to do this is to use a special redirect string called urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob. I've got this set in my Coinbase application setting and I also pass it in the config with react-native-app-auth. What happens is once I authorize I just get a blank screen in my mobile with only a cancel option. I cancel it just takes me back to the app as though I never initiated the request. I think I must be missing something to allow xcode to catch the redirect and pass me back to the app.

index.js:

```
import { authorize } from 'react-native-app-auth';

const config = {
    issuer: 'https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize',
    clientId: '<removed',
    redirectUrl: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
    scopes: ['wallet:accounts:read'],
    serviceConfiguration: {
        authorizationEndpoint: 'https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize',
        tokenEndpoint: 'https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/token',
        revocationEndpoint: 'https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/revoke'
    }
};

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        authorize(config)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Text>OAuth</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RNAppAuthAuthorizationFlowManager.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,     RNAppAuthAuthorizationFlowManager>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <RNAppAuthAuthorizationFlowManagerDelegate>authorizationFlowManagerDelegate;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working. You need to setup an URL Scheme and [Deep Linking](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) in Xcode and React Native. For example I used "MyApp" in the URL Scheme. So now after authorization Coinbase redirects back to MyApp://oauth which switches me back to my app. It all works really seamlessly. I can see it worked as I get an email from Coinbase saying the application has been successfully linked to my account. I was also able to verify my Deep Linking works by going to MyApp:// in Safari which switched me back to my app without an issue.

I have another issue now. Although the authorization worked and I was switched back to my app I didn't see anything being captured in React Native. I should be able to see the token.

On the React Native page it says this should catch it...

```
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
},
componentWillUnmount() {
  Linking.removeEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
},
_handleOpenURL(event) {
  console.log(event.url);
}
```

Does anyone how how I can either query or check the token that was received? The authorization function in react-native-app-auth doesn't return anything and the Deep Linking listener didn't seem to return anything.

Comment: Please do not ask secondary questions in your answers. If you have a new problem now, you should ask a separate question.